# How to keep track of the degree value given to a skew transformation?

Tags: corel-draw, skew

I am using a font that does not have an italic or bold versions.
To simulate italic, I am typing the text, clicking over it, selecting and draging the top-middle point to the right, thus changing the angle to a negative value.

[image: practical example]

### How can I keep track of the dragged distance (degree given) ?

The idea here is to reuse the value on other words or objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a method that applies practically to any software, the "object manager" for this case, or "layer manager" for other software, where we can rename the object/layer and add to it the transformation name and value:

## Apply a skew value

The image bellow demonstrates the application of a skew value using the transformation toolbar, that allows for a more precise transformation:

[image: Add a skew value]

<sup>After the current object loses selection, the skew value will no longer be present.</sup>

## Save the value for later:

To keep track of the value initially entered, you can rename the object and add to its name the skew transformation and value used.

[image: Object Manager]

Answer (score 2):

I find the best answer to this for any software is to manually create detailed notes. There are many applications which fail to record or remember things like transformation angles.

By simply having a text document open while working I can insert values and reference what objects they were applied to. Later I can merely check the text file to know what angles were used.